# Multer file address to upload folder is not well formatted in MySQL database

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer, file-format

I used Multer `Node.js` modules to upload image to upload folder and the image uploaded fine and the correct path was passed to the `MySQL` database but the file path of the file(image) is not well formatted as i expected.

I mean there is no slash (/) between the main folder, subfolder and the file(image) actual name though the extension is correct.

```js
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: "./public/upload/",
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() +
            file.originalname)
    }
})

const upload = multer({
    storage: storage
})
```

but this is the kind of data gotten from database when i make a request

```js
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "samsung galax s8",
        "brand": "samsung",
        "image": "publicuploadfile-1547151173379tecno-spak-2.jpg",
        "category": "phone",
        "qty": "6",
        "price": "50000",
        "created_at": "1/10/2019",
        "updated_at": "1/10/2019"
    }
]
```

This is the image file.path I got **"publicuploadfile-1547151173379tecno-spak-2.jpg"**,

Instead of something like **"public/upload/file-1547151173379tecno-spak-2.jpg"**, which I was expecting.

Please how can I save the path to the database as the correct file address?

Answer (score 1):

Update this .

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads')
  },
  filename: function(req, file, callback) {
    console.log(file)
    callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, i saw that when i used a raw sql query to save req.file.path mysql engine would strip off my backslash '\' but when i used bulk insert to insert multiple file urls at once it did not strip off the backslash.

Example,
  temp[i] = {'recordedWebinarVideo': req.files[i].path}

```
  con.query('UPDATE `courses` SET `Recorded_URL` = "'+temp[i].recordedWebinarVideo+'" 
   WHERE `CourseID`="'+req.params.id+'" ', (err,data)=>{
    if(err)
    console.log(err)
    else{
      console.log(data)

    }
  })
```

RESULT : BACKSLASH removed

However, 
with

con.query('INSERT INTO `course_extra_resources` (`file_path`, `course_id`) VALUES ?', 
      [temp.map( i => [i.files, req.params.id])], (err,data)=>
       {
          if(err)
          console.log(err);
          else{
            console.log(data)
            res.status(200).json(data)
          }
       })
The backslash was pertained and mysql saved the url in correct format.